# Why are my variables empty on first click Apollo Client React?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to call useMutation when I click on the "Save" button on a modal. However, the first time I click it, the variables which get sent are empty (i can see the variables in the network calls tab and all are undefined) even though when I do a console.log I can see the data.

I.e

```
let globalState = {};

const SessionAdd = () => {
    console.log(globalState);   // This always displays the correct data when I click on the "Save" button. 
    const [AddsessionInput, {error} ] = useMutation(addSession,{
        variables: { 
            title:String(globalState.title),
            description:String(globalState.description)
        }
    });
  return (
    <div className="AddSession">
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
            <i className='fas fa-plus' /> Create a new Session
        </Button>

        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} size="md">
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title><i className='fas fa-camera' /> Create details</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body> <AddSessionForm /> </Modal.Body>

                <Button variant="primary" onClick={AddsessionInput}>
                    Save
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

const AddSessionForm = () =>{

     const [sessionDetails, setSessionDetails] = useState({
        title:""
    });

    const handleSessionDetails = (evt) => {
        sessionDetails[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
        setSessionDetails(sessionDetails);
        globalState = sessionDetails;  
    };

return(
    <div>
        <p><strong>Add title</strong></p>
        <FormControl name="title"
         onChange={handleSessionDetails}/>
        <br/>
  );
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle states when dealing with a parent component (i.e handling objects in child components from parent state)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably refactor it slightly:

```
const [AddSessionInput, {error}] = useMutation(QUERY_STRING);

const runAddSessionInput = async () => {
  await AddSessionInput({ variables });
};
```

In your onClick:

```
return (
  <Button variant="primary" onClick={runAddSessionInput} />
);
```